# Check if Label text created in code contains specific string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have several labels and textboxes created and the number of them depends on what the user types into a textbox, i.e. 5 typed in so there would be 5 labels and 5 textboxes.
I can recursively search out all labels which name is "myLabel" & var, var = number 1 through 5 in this example.
What i have is a context menu for the labels with 3 items. Item 1 changes the label text to whatever the user wants, numbers, letters, and/or symbols. Item 2 and 3 is what i am having trouble with.
Item 2 needs to change the label text to D1 the first time it is initiated, then it needs to change it to D2 the second time and if a third time is invoked an error should not let them continue.
Item 3 is the same as 2, except the text should be S1 and S2 respectively. 
What I have so far is this, however i keep getting stuck in a loop or it doesn't change the label.text to what i want. Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub lblMenuItem3_Click()

    label = lblContextMenu.SourceControl.Name

    For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is Label Then
            Dim myLabel As Label = DirectCast(control, Label)
            Dim str As String = myLabel.Text
            'If myLabel.Text = "S1" Then
            If LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S1")) Then

                'MessageBox.Show("That string is in here!")
                Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S2"
            Else

                'MessageBox.Show("The string is not in here!")
                Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S1"
            End If
        Else
            Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S1"
            'End If
        End If
    Next

    'Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S1"
    'Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S2"
End Sub
```

EDIT1:
This code is partially working as i need it to, but for some reason it runs the sub the number of times equal to the number of labels on the form and I'm not sure why

```
Private Sub lblMenuItem3_Click()

    label = lblContextMenu.SourceControl.Name

    Dim s1lbl As Boolean = False
    Dim s2lbl As Boolean = False
    For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is Label Then
            Dim myLabel As Label = DirectCast(control, Label)
            Dim str As String = myLabel.Text
            If LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S1")) Then
                s1lbl = True
                Exit For
            ElseIf LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S2")) Then
                s2lbl = True
                Exit For
            Else
                Continue For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If s1lbl = False AndAlso s2lbl = False Then
        Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If s1lbl = True AndAlso s2lbl = False Then
        Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S2"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If s1lbl = False AndAlso s2lbl = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Too many Shallow points, only 2 allowed.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

this is the code:

```
    Private Sub TextBoxABPts_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBoxABPts.KeyPress
    For i = 1 To TextBoxABPts.Text
            lbl1 = New Label()
            lbl1.Location = New Point(2, 165 + 25 * (i - 1))
            lbl1.Name = "myLabel" & i
            lbl1.Text = i
            Me.Controls.Add(lbl1)


            AddHandler lblMenuItem1.Click, AddressOf lblMenuItem1_Click
            AddHandler lblMenuItem2.Click, AddressOf lblMenuItem2_Click
            AddHandler lblMenuItem3.Click, AddressOf lblMenuItem3_Click
            lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(lblMenuItem1)
            lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(lblMenuItem2)
            lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(lblMenuItem3)
            lbl1.ContextMenu = lblContextMenu

        Next i
        TextBoxABDist.Focus()
    End If
```

Comment: It would help if you could show the code where lblMenuItem3_Click() is being fired from.

Comment: @Neal This is the code for the label creation and the addhandler for the menu items, it is within a button click

Comment: lblContextMenu isn't being created new for each lbl1. You should try and either clear the MenuItems after adding it each time or create it new inside the for loop each time.

Comment: @Neal  `lblContextMenu as new ContextMenu` is outside the sub as a dim withevents so i can reference it later in the `lblMenuItem*.Click`. Is there another way I can get this? I am apparently lost.

Comment: I have a better idea what you are looking for now. Have a look at my edited answer. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you out:
Add your menu items to the lblContextMenu outside the for loop where ever you create the lblContextMenu

```
    lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("click1", New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.lblMenuItem1_Click1))
    lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("click2", New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.lblMenuItem1_Click2))
    lblContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("click3", New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.lblMenuItem1_Click3))
```

Then in your for loop just add the contextmenu to the labels:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To TextBoxABPts.Text
        Dim lbl1 = New Label()
        lbl1.Location = New Point(2, 165 + 25 * (i - 1))
        lbl1.Name = "myLabel" & i
        lbl1.Text = i
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl1)
        lbl1.ContextMenu = lblContextMenu
    Next i.
```

Then as an example your menu click sub might look something like this:

```
    Private Sub lblMenuItem1_Click1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim mi As MenuItem = CType(sender, MenuItem)
    Dim menu As ContextMenu = mi.GetContextMenu()
    Dim lbl As Label = CType(menu.SourceControl, Label)
    lbl.Text = mi.Text
    End Sub
```

You'll need to combine this with your current ifelse logic.

Comment: this is used to only change the label that was right clicked on

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
If LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S1")) Then

    'MessageBox.Show("That string is in here!")
    Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S2"
Else

    'MessageBox.Show("The string is not in here!")
    Me.Controls.Item(label).Text = "S1"
End If
```

Should be this:

```
If LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S1")) Then

    'MessageBox.Show("That string is in here!")
    myLabel.Text = "S2"
ElseIf LCase(str).Contains(LCase("S2"))

    'MessageBox.Show("Bad Stuff!")
    ' Do your S3 error things here
Else
    'MessageBox.Show("No S Value Found!")
    myLabel.Text = "S1"
End If
```

Without the ElseIf structure, you will alternate between setting it as S1 or S2, and there is no other option. With the structure in place you check for all possibilities and it shouldn't loop.

Comment: dang that seems obvious and easy! thank you i will check it out

Comment: close but not working correctly, perhaps some more info: the code needs to only change the label right clicked on. Currently the first initiation sets it to s1, but then when we get to s2 it changes it to s2 but continues the loop and errors on the elseif showing the message box the number of times there are labels, i.e. if there are 10 labels the elseif error will show 10 times

Comment: You are looping through all of the controls in the form looking for any Label. Michael Z's answer shows you what you should be trying to do. 

You need to only perform this method on the Label that is actually clicked instead of all of them.

Comment: But i also need to search all labels to see whether any include "S1" or "S2" I cannot have (2) or more S1 or S2. Loop through all labels, check for string s1, if it does not exist change only the label that was right clicked on to s1, if it does exist change only the label clicked on to s2. if s2 exists(presumably a 3rd time clicking) then sub needs to exit w/o any changes. I have no idea what Michael Z is trying to do other than grab labels as type only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper signature in your method. It should look like this.

```
Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Then you can cast sender to a Label and set the text.

```
Ctype(sender, Label).Text = "S1"
```